# Problems using #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the boost header file #include 
 to but it keeps giving me an error saying   no such file/directory exists

Comment: Then you don't have boost installed.

Answer (score 4):

tell the compiler where he could find your boost installation (or the boost header files).

if they are, e.g. here

```
/usr/local/include/boost/algorithm/string.hpp
```

and your compiler may be g++ (the gnu c++ compiler), then this options would help:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include
```

it is a `-I`, a capital i.

Make sure, that boost is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a -I directive in your makefile or whatever you are using to compile to tell the compiler the path to the boost headers. Find out where on your system the boost headers are and give your compiler:  -I/path/to/boost where /path/to/boost is the path to the directory containing the boost headers.